# Make sure that mocked GTest method overrides virtual method

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual, googletest

I would like to make sure that a mocked method overrides base class virtual method. Is it possible to use `MOCK_METHOD` in the way when it generates method marked as `override`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by specifying the specs parameter to the MOCK_METHOD like so,

```cpp
MOCK_METHOD(void, foo, (), (override));
```

Quoting https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#creating-mock-classes

> The first 3 parameters are simply the method declaration, split into 3
>   parts. The 4th parameter accepts a closed list of qualifiers, which
>   affect the generated method:
>
> - const - Makes the mocked method a const method. Required if overriding a const method.
> - override - Marks the method with override. Recommended if overriding a virtual method.

Here is a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/VMJmGK) on godbolt.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need